# R fable aggregate with mean

Tags: r, fable-r

```
require(dplyr)
require(fable)
require(tsibble)
```

Build a simple tsibble object

```
d <- tibble(
   t = c(1:15, 1:15),
   f = rep (letters[1:2] , each = 15),
   x = c(rpois(15, 10), rpois(15, 1)))

d <- as_tsibble(d, index = t, key = f)
```

Provide the tsibble with an aggregation_key

```
d <- d %>% aggregate_key(f , x = mean(x))
```

Check results and it works

```
autoplot(d)
```

[image]

Split trn and tst

```
trn <- d %>% filter_index (.~10)
tst <- d %>% filter_index (11~.)
```

Fit simple average model

```
fm <- trn %>% model ( mean = MEAN(x))
```

Reconcile

```
fm <- fm %>% reconcile( mean = bottom_up(mean))
```

Forecast

```
fc <- forecast ( fm, h=5)
```

Plot Forecast

```
autoplot(fc, d, level = NULL, color = 'red')
```

[image]

It seems that forecast uses `sum` as aggregation function rather than `mean`.

Am I missing something?
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: `reconcile()` is designed to work with additive hierarchies. The ability to compute non-additive summaries (such as the `mean()`, or `any()`), is useful for computing aggregates of exogenous regressors.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the `bottom-up`? Without it it's forecasting the aggregated mean per below:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(fable))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tsibble))

d <- tibble(
  t = c(1:15, 1:15),
  f = rep (letters[1:2] , each = 15),
  x = c(rpois(15, 10), rpois(15, 1)))

d <- as_tsibble(d, index = t, key = f)

d <- d %>% aggregate_key(f , x = mean(x))

# autoplot(d)

trn <- d %>% filter_index(.~10)
tst <- d %>% filter_index(11~.)

fm <- trn %>% model(mean = MEAN(x))

# fm <- fm %>% reconcile(mean = bottom_up(mean))

fc <- forecast (fm, h = 5)

autoplot(fc, d, level = NULL, color = 'red')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>